# Can't hide Fusion Charts graphics watermark when Generating a PDF with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, pdf, puppeteer, ejs, fusioncharts

I'm having a problem when generating with Puppeteer a PDF that contains [Fusion Charts](https://www.fusioncharts.com/) graphics.

We have the license key for Fusion Charts Enterprise plan, so the *FusionCharts Trial* watermark should not be visible at all.

This is the code related to the PDF generation:

```
  const [page, browser] = await launchPuppeteer({ clientTz });

  const content = await renderTemplate('dashboard')({ dashboard, licenseKey: FUSION_CHARTS_LICENSE_KEY_ID });

  const { height, width } = PDF_DEFAULT_OPTIONS;
  await page.setViewport({ width, height });
  await page.setContent(content, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

  const pdfContent = await page.pdf({
    ...PDF_DEFAULT_OPTIONS
    , headerTemplate: headerTemplate({ dashboard, profile })
    , footerTemplate
  });
```

Variable `content` contains the generated HTML after rendered with an EJS template.

If I run that HTML in the browser directly, it works fine, and it does not show the Fusion Charts watermark. But when I generate the PDF with Puppeeter, the watermark is always visible.

This is the EJS template HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/3.16.0/fusioncharts.js'></script>
        <script src='https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/3.16.0/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion.js'></script>
    </head>
    ...
 
    <script>
 
        FusionCharts.ready(function() {

            const _licenseKey = <%- JSON.stringify(licenseKey) %>;
            FusionCharts.options.license({ key: _licenseKey, creditLabel: false });

            // With this, I just make sure my licenseKey is correct
            const license = document.createElement('p');
            license.innerHTML = `License key: <br>${_licenseKey}`;
            document.body.append(license);
            ...
            ...
 
            new FusionCharts(graphicData.data).render();
        });
 
    </script>
 
</html>
```

So, basically, after a lot of different approachs and tries, I've reached the conclusion the problem is related with Puppeteer and how it generates the PDF from the HTML (maybe the version of Chromium it uses...). So maybe there are some Puppeteer options related with this issue that I'm not aware of...

**EDIT** (07-09-2021)

I've replicated my code in a much simpler local Puppeteer test with node, just loading PDF content from and HTML file, and also is not working, license is not being applied.

Comment: @daniegarcia : Please drop a mail to support@fusioncharts.com, if you have an enterprise license you can use fusionexport which also runs on puppeteer, you can pass the license key effortlessly in that case.

https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/exporting-charts/using-fusionexport/overview
https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/exporting-charts/using-fusionexport/fusionexport-license-activation

Comment: @Zapdos13 for now I need to stick to what I have because is shared code with other services of our system, so we can't migrate right now to the use of FusionExport. Anayway, if it alos runs on Puppeteer, why is not working then even running a local Puppeteer?

Comment: @KJ that should not be the problem, license is working fine in a browser with localhost in development, and is not restricted by IP neither.

Comment: Try adding the key at the end of the file of fusioncharts.js, so whenever the file will load it will have the key applied

Answer (score 0):

Finally we've found a solution/workaround for the the problem in hand.

We've just added:

```
// Added these two lines
await page.goto('https://example.com');
await page.setCacheEnabled(false);

await page.setContent(content, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
const pdfContent = await page.pdf({.....
```

This way we make sure all requests made from out HTML have a valid origin/referer, in this case `https://example.com`.

Which seems to be related with my initial problem. Maybe is just some restriction of use/security by Fusion Charts...